# Why is the area under a Probability Disstribution function as calculated from a cdf not equal to 1?

Tags: python, probability, probability-density, probability-distribution

So, I have a set of probabilities (z_scaled) and I'm trying to plot the PDF of the distribution as well as the CDF. Now my code is as follows:

```
cdf = np.cumsum(z_scaled)
pdf = np.gradient(cdf)
```

Now, the cdf looks like so:

[image: CDF]

And the PDF, as calculated from the CDF using the gradient function looks like so:

[image: PDF]

My question is, why is the area under the PDF as calculated from this, not equal to 1?

Comment: What is it equal to? I would hazard a guess that you've run into a floating point arithmetic problem -- http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Its a finite value equal to around 0.004538. I dont think its running into floating point problems though

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937979/calculating-the-derivative-of-cumulative-density-function-in-python

Comment: Note that `Numpy.gradient` takes an optional second argument which is the spacing between the samples. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937979 as suggested.